# Should Java classes call super() when they have no parent class?

Tags: java, oop, super

Is it necessary or good practice to call `super()` when you're class only has `Object` as a parent?

i.e.

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo() {
    super();

    // Other stuff
  }
}
```

or

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo() {
    // Other stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. It's implicitly invoked, so theres no reason to call it.

Comment: As discussed in the duplicate, there's also no reason to *ever* call it, regardless of what the parent class is.

Comment: @Duncan If the superclass's constructor requires paramerers, it's required, so I wouldn't say there's no reason to ever call it.

Comment: I believe this question is specifically related to the no-arg `super();` call.

Comment: @Duncan I'm sorry. I'm caught up in so many things, I forgot this was specific to classes that implicitly extend Object